# Not able to link a Carthage framework to Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, entity-framework, carthage

I am trying to link a new framework downloaded via Carthage to one of my project but getting a linker error:

[image]

I'm following these steps:

1. Updated the Cartfile with the framework location.
2. Run `carthage update` command to fetch the framework.
3. Under project target -> Build Phase added a new Run script and renamed it to Framework Copy.
4. Added the script to copy the framework from the file system : `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/CleanroomLogger.framework`.
5. Dragged and dropped the framework from the mentioned location under `Link Binary With Libraries` section of project target -> Build Phase.
6. Double checked the `Framework Search Path` under build settings and it seems to be set correctly : `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually it turned out to be deployment target issue. The framework I was linking was supported with minimum deployment target as 8 and I was running with 7 :). I wish the build error could be more descriptive.